# Backbone collection and templates where models properties are not uniformly named

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, view, model

I have 4 models, each of which have *different* properties.  For instance one might look like {total: 4}, and another might be {change: .5}.  These models will be displayed with the SAME format, i.e. they will look the same as far as rendering HTML goes.  I'm wondering if this is an appropriate case to use a collection and create the same view for each model.  I'm confused because it would be ideal to use the same template for each view, but in the template for one I would have to display properties like <%= total %> and <%= change %> for another.  I don't think it would be correct to check for which model it is in the template, so I'm wondering should I make a new template for each model (even though the only difference in the template would be the name of the property), or maybe I should rename the model properties within each model so that they all match.  Here is some code which is hopefully enough to understand the issue.

```
var Chart = Backbone.Model.extend({ initialize: function() { console.log('please work')}});
chart1 = new Chart({title: 'total', total: 123});
chart2 = new Chart({title: 'change', difference: '20%'});

var ChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
className: "chart-container",
template: $("#chartTemplate").html(),

render: function () {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
});

var Charts = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Chart});
var myCharts = new Charts([chart1, chart2]);

var MasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#charts"),

initialize: function () {
    this.collection = myCharts;
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (model) {
        that.renderChart(model);
    }, this);
},

renderChart: function (model) {
    var chartView = new ChartView({
        model: model
    });
    this.$el.append(chartView.render().el);
}
});
```

Template:

```
<script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">
<h1> <%= title%></h1>
<p> <%= total? difference? %></p>
</script>
```

Some insight on the best way to go about this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to pass `model.toJSON()` to the template function, you can mangle `toJSON()` into a different form...

Comment: can you elaborate on that a bit?  I'm not sure I understand.  (still very new to backbone)

Comment: Perhaps a more complete example of what you're trying to do would make it easier for us to talk about.

Comment: ok I posted some code that hopefully will clear up this question.  and mu, my fellow snowboarder, thanks for being on top of all my backbone questions =) really appreciate it.

Comment: I think relynt's **EDIT** approach makes sense. Somewhere you need to normalize the attributes. If you want to use a collection then you should normalize them in the model so that the collection makes sense; if you don't need a collection then you could use some sort of adapter  (a method on the model perhaps) to let the view know what things are called in the model and then the view can map things to match the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using BackboneJS, you do not have to explicitly tie collections to templates. What you can do, though, is create a more generic template, then pass in the value you want to render.

IE

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#myElement'),
  render: function(text) {
    this.$el.html("<p>My Text: "+text+"</p>");
    return this;
  }
});
```

Then, when you call your render method, just pass the text you want to render. That way, it does not matter which model or collection you are using, just pass what is necessary.

**EDIT**

Ok, so looking at your code, I now understand where you are coming from. I believe that have the same model with different attributes is not a good practice. Backbone models are meant to mirror that of your models on the server side. Instead of having different attributes between the two models, find two attribute names that will define both of your values.

Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/4cYhh/

Note that instead of having an attribute of "total" and an attribute of "difference", there is now just two common attributes: name and value. Of course, this assumes that you won't add any more attributes that will be different from each other.

Hope this makes some sense. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: In that case wouldn't I need 4 different views for 4 different models?  Ideally I'd want to reuse both the view and template.

Comment: You would need to setup a callback for an event on the model. For example, you would setup an 'update' method to be called when a sync happens on the model. Inside of that update method, you would call this particular render. Because you setup this callback in each model, you would know what attribute to pass to render.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single template, and introduce a serialize function in model, which serialize your model data into something the template can understand. Then change

```
 this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
```

to

```
 this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.serialize()));
```

This is not something new, I remember this pattern being used in Backbone Layoutmanager.